# When validating collections, is there a way to know the position a bean being validated from within custom constraint validator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-validator, jsr349

Lets take this below use case.

I have bean with collection of some other bean as one of its properties:

```
public class MyBean {
    ...
    @Valid
    private NestedBean[] nestedBeans;
    ...
}
```

The nested bean has a custom class level constraint like this:

```
@SomeConstraint
public class NestedBean {
    ...
}
```

And we have a validator that validates this custom constraint:

```
public SomeConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<SomeConstraint, NestedBean> {
    ...
    public boolean isValid(NestedBean bean, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to know the position of the current "bean" object that is getting validated, so that we can show error messages like:

"The third nested bean is invalid...."

Or is there any other way to achieve this?

The Hibernate's ConstraintValidationContext implementation hold property path with these details, but is not a public API.

Comment: You could try creating a validator for `NestedBean[]` directly and iterate over the array inside the `isValid` method. Then you would know the index. Something like `ConstraintValidator<SomeConstration,NestedBean[]>`

Comment: Correct, I just wanted to check if we can get something from the framework itself. As I said, the ContraintValidatorContext actually has that information (as part of nodePath) but it is not a public API.